# JS lodash uniq not woking with ObjectID list

Tags: lodash, objectid

I have a collection of mongoose models, I tried to use `uniq` `lodash` function to get unique id`s from the list, but still get the same list.

List elements are https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

```
const uniqueIds = uniq(ids) // not working
```

input:

```
[ 
  5c6f98ceb3f013291b497d82,
  5c6e447147c75d699f0514a1,
  5c6e447147c75d699f0514a1,
  5c6e447147c75d699f0514a1,
  5c6f98cfb3f013291b497d89,
  5c6f98cfb3f013291b497d89,
  5c6f98cfb3f013291b497d89,
  5c6f98cfb3f013291b497d89,
  5c6f98cfb3f013291b497d89,
  5c6f98cfb3f013291b497d89 
]
```

output:

```
    [ 
      5c6f98ceb3f013291b497d82,
      5c6e447147c75d699f0514a1,
      5c6e447147c75d699f0514a1,
      5c6e447147c75d699f0514a1,
      5c6f98cfb3f013291b497d89,
      5c6f98cfb3f013291b497d89,
      5c6f98cfb3f013291b497d89,
      5c6f98cfb3f013291b497d89,
      5c6f98cfb3f013291b497d89,
      5c6f98cfb3f013291b497d89
    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that these are `ObjectId` objects, and probably a new one is generated for the same hash, so in that case, the references aren't the same the following will probably happen:

```
ObjectId("foo") == ObjectId("foo"); // false
```

In that case `uniq()` won't be able to recognize the same `ObjectId`. A solution would be to use [`uniqBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#uniqBy) to properly compare them, for example:

```
_.uniqBy(ids, id => id.valueOf());
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the items are instances of [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/), you can't use `_.uniq()` because different object instances are always unique. You can use lodash's [`_.uniqBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#uniqBy), with the `str` property of the object as the unique identifier:

```
_.uniqBy(list, 'str')
```

Comment: my items are https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/ not strings, maybe it is problem

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the list is array, each element in the list is of the ObjectId, this should work. Each id in the list will be iterated and converted to sting for finding the unique elements

```
_.uniqBy(list, (id) => id.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work even for objectId arrays

```
 function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
      return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    }
    
    const uniqueArray=yourArray.filter(onlyUnique);
```